# Pycharm hangs on unittests indefinitely if there is a print statement present

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest

I set up a brand new PyCharm project to test this in. As of several hours ago, I could have print statements all over the place with no problem whatsoever. As of right now, having any print statements within any project causes the whole process to spin forever, eventually being closed out automatically by my OS with the code 137 SIGKILL 9 command.

The following code is the most stripped down demonstration of this I could come up with:

```py
import unittest

def hellothere():
    pass

class TestTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        stuff = hellothere()
        print(stuff)

    def test(self):
        pass
```

It's worth noting that changing `stuff = hellothere()` to `stuff = str(hellothere())` and removing the print works, and returning instead of printing works as well.

I tried setting this up in terminal, but when I run this in terminal, I get `ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.TestTest'>: runTest`.

dmesg reports `low swap: killing largest compressed process with pid 6093 (python2.7) and size 1051 MB` but I can't find any other relevant information in there.

I'm using pycharm verion info below:
[image]

and python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange behaviour, maybe you reduced example does not have something your original code does have?

I tried this code:

```
import unittest

def hellothere():
    pass

class TestTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.stuff = hellothere()
        print("this is", self.stuff)

    # fixed: you need test_ for test discovery 
    def test_smth(self):
        pass
        assert self.stuff is None    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It works both as `python test_abc.py` and `python -m unittest test_abc` with following result:

```
this is None                                                            
.                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Ran 1 test in 0.001s                                                    

OK
```

There has to be something else that makes the test go to infinite loop. I'd go with trying to run tests in console without pycharm for further inspection.

Update: below is OP solution to the problem, it is related to virtual envirnoments. We still do not know what choked the `print()` in unittests, but learnt to avoid it.

My lesson is that with heavyweight IDE like PyCharm try to replicate any problem in commandline. Also it seems IntelliJ support is quite responsive [on similar issues](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000667950-PyCharm-Unit-test-fails).

> I just figured it out. The virtual environment that was being used in my project interpreter was just copied over when I created a new project which is why creating a new project didn't fix it. I created a new interpreter with a new virtual environment, and problem solved!

Comment: When I try `python -m unittest test_abc` from the folder that holds the unittests it tells me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_abc'` , I also tried `python -m test_main test_smth` (test_main is the name of my file) and I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_smth'`

Comment: Maybe try from one folder up. If you are in test folder python cannot discover the code under test. You would have something like `python -m unittest test/test_abc.py`

Comment: or just plain `python -m unittest`, with test discovery

Comment: Was able to run just by running `python test_main.py` and it works fine in terminal. Interestingly enough, it also works if I run it from the Pycharm terminal in the same virtual environment. It only doesn't work if I run it via the play button in Pycharm or by right clicking the file and clicking `Run unittests in 'main_test.py'`

Comment: Just as a precaution I just tried reinstalling PyCharm and it didn't do anything, so I'm still in the dark

Comment: IDE's are there to confuse you ) You can inspect some of PyCharm settings further,, but likely it is not a print statement that causes trouble.

Comment: All I can tell is that with print statement, it doesn't work, without print statement, and nothing else changed in any way, it does work. It also doesn't matter what I'm printing, I can even just say print() and it hangs. I didn't even change any settings throughout the day.

Comment: A print() outside the tests hangs an IDE?

Comment: Only if it's in the test itself or if it's in the function being called by the tests. If it's a global print or part of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, it works fine

Comment: I just figured it out. The virtual environment that was being used in my project interpreter was just copied over when I created a new project which is why creating a new project didn't fix it. I created a new interpreter with a new virtual environment, and problem solved!